# Browser extension allowing persistent local storage, not cleared when clearing browser data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any storage similar to local storage in html5 which does not clear on clearing the browsing data?

Note: It's not necessarily required to store in web browser. Any third-party library can also be used except storing in a database.

Comment: Any such solution will require the user to actively install something beforehand, is that OK? So, you are looking for a browser extension that provides such persistent storage, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes it is completely fine to install such extensions which aids in persisting data if availabale any.